# Fedora 27: No match for argument: kernel-devel-4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I am attempting to run the virtualbox package from rpmfusion-free-updates on Fedora 27 however when I start a VM I get the error

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is probably not
>   loaded.You may not have kernel driver installed for kernel that is
>   runnig, if so you may do as root: dnf install akmod-VirtualBox
>   kernel-devel-$(uname -r)If you installed VirtualBox packages and don't
>   want reboot the system, you may need load the kernel driver, doing as
>   root: akmods; systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service

I ran the suggested command and got

```
$ sudo dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
Last metadata expiration check: 0:51:14 ago on Fri 16 Mar 2018 10:10:02 ACDT.
Package akmod-VirtualBox-5.2.6-2.fc27.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
No match for argument: kernel-devel-4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match
```

How can I install `kernel-devel-4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64` to get virtualbox working?

There don't seem to be any packages with this name

```
$ dnf search kernel-devel-
Last metadata expiration check: 6 days, 23:57:26 ago on Fri 09 Mar 2018 11:01:08 ACDT.
No matches found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out this package seems to be called `kernel-devel` which automatically grabs the latest version. This package was installed but it was at a newer version than my running kernel so I simply had to reboot to get my running kernel to the same version in the repos.

Comment: Note that you can type in the package version yourself so that you can build against the newer kernel without rebooting (although you will need to reboot when you want to actually use the kernel module, since it's for a newer kernel).