# Unable to find a match for kernel devel version

Tags: centos, kernel

I am attempting to use make to build something, but it seems that `/lib/modules/4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64/build` is missing.

Previously when I encountered a similar problem with a different version kernel, the command `sudo yum install "kernel-devel-$(uname -r)"` worked, but this time it says:

`No match for argument: kernel-devel-4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64`

running `sudo yum install kernel-devel` outputs

```
Package kernel-devel-4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-devel-4.18.0-394.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

where it seems that it's already installed for later versions.

[Another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430523/fedora-27-no-match-for-argument-kernel-devel-4-14-16-300-fc27-x86-64) suggests that a reboot would fix this problem, by upgrading the kernel. The kernel was purposefully downgraded because we suspect that what we are trying to do doesn't work with a higher level kernel. Additionally, rebooting the machine seemed to not fix anything.

How do I fix this, installing the correct version of kernel-devel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the package [can be found here](https://koji.mbox.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=17240). Downloaded it as an rpm, used `yum remove kernel-devel` do get rid of the newer installations, and then installed from the rpm package, which worked